# GLSL vector addition vs multiple floats

Tags: glsl, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

Say i have this:

```
float x2 = q.x + q.x;
float y2 = q.y + q.y;
float z2 = q.z + q.z;
```

vs this:

```
vec3 q2 = q.xyz + q.xyz;
```

Is the vector operation better / faster or is this not a concern at GLSL level?

Comment: You might find [this article](http://aras-p.info/blog/2010/09/29/glsl-optimizer/) interesting

Comment: I think i tried this a loong time ago and i couldn't get it to work. I'll give it another shot. I'm confused though, i want to take the tools from the answer for a spin, but im not sure how the generated assembly can be relevant if it's generated differently for different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its faster, GPUs are optimized for vectorized operations, using tools like [AMDs ShaderAnalyzer](http://gpuopen.com/archive/) or [NVIDIAs nSight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) you can see the generated assembly revealing that your first snippet results in 3 scalar ops whereas your second one is a single vector op.